# RBAC privileges for Azure Function App Deployment Center Logs in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal, azure-deployment

What RBAC privileges are required for viewing the logs for Azure Functions in "Function App -> Deployment Center -> Logs"  that have info on the provisioning phase?

This is the error gotten

> Failed to load container logs: The client 'xyz@abc.com' with object id 'hdgjksdgjkdhgjdhg' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/containerlogs/action' over scope '/subscriptions/lajflkasjfksjfklsjf' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

> What RBAC privileges are required for viewing the logs for Azure Functions in "Function App -> Deployment Center -> Logs" that have info on the provisioning phase?

- To view logs, we need a `Contributor` or `Owner` role.
- We can check our role in `Access control(IAM)` of the deployed `Azure Function`.
- You can see I have a `Contributor` role.

[image]

- Iam able to see the logs without any error.

[image]

The error clearly indicates that the user `xyz@abc.com` does not permissions to view the logs on the selected subscription.

- I tried to add the role, but you can see the option is disabled.

[image]

- Only the user with `Owner` role can assign the roles in RBAC.

We can see the same in the `Azure Portal` => `Subscriptions` => `Access control (IAM)`.

[image]

> If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

As suggested in the error, try to refresh the credentials/ try to signout and signin again to reflect the latest changes.